# React.js button and event handling for lists having cards

Tags: reactjs, button, event-handling, card, static-data

- **overview** : creating 3 different lists with cards ; each list has a specific button type(depending upon list title) and say,each card in list X has a specific button X associated with it.

[what i have created so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0caN.png)

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM9Uy.png)

my question is how can i create buttons with different value like in doing list,there needs to be button with different value.

another question is,can i move a card from one list to another list via button click events using static data in[data.js - part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nicw9.png) and [data.js - part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNRiC.png)?

github link : https://github.com/atom19-i/ToDoList

Comment: Adding image is not useful , please add some code or create a sandbox with the minimal reproduceable example so that it will be easier to help .

Comment: added github link for the same,please take a look